# iOS - Can we add Promo codes for In-App Purchase for non-consumable product?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to implement In-app purchase with promo code to my application, but i was wondering if Promo Codes are supported for non-consumable product and also how do we detect if the promo code is applied or not.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, promo codes are available for any type of in-app purchase product type, including non-consumables.

Your app responds to a user using a promo code the same way as it would respond to any other purchase or when you implement a "restore purchases" feature.

Comment: Thanks, but can you help me out with some resources or ways to implement in-app purchase with promo codes.

Comment: There's nothing special about implementing promo codes for in-app purchases. If your app supports in-app purchases properly then it automatically supports promo codes without any additional code.

Comment: I was hoping for something like this, but do you know if you have to enable something in AppStore Connect maybe to enable this? Because I don't have the option for the "Promo Codes" everybody is talking about :)